# How to code date range using 2 DTPicker with Two (2) Table

Tags: sql-server, vb6

```
Private Sub DTPicker3_Change()

   loadData "Select  CheckItem as 'Check Item',CheckItem as 'Check Item',ItemNo as 'Item No.',Criteria as 'Criteria',Mcname as 'Machine Name',AMstart as 'Start of Shift' ,AMafter as 'After 1st break',PMstart as 'Start of Shift' ,PMafter as 'After 1st break',CheckDate FROM tbl_Checklist where CheckDate BETWEEN '" & DTPicker2.Value & "'AND  '" & DTPicker3.Value & " '" '

 End Sub


Private Sub DTPicker2_Change()

  loadData "Select  CheckItem as 'Check Item',CheckItem as 'Check Item',ItemNo as 'Item No.',Criteria as 'Criteria',Mcname as 'Machine Name',AMstart as 'Start of Shift' ,AMafter as 'After 1st break',PMstart as 'Start of Shift' ,PMafter as 'After 1st break',CheckDate FROM tbl_Checklist  where CheckDate BETWEEN '" & DTPicker2.Value & "'AND  '" & DTPicker3.Value & "'" 
End Sub
```

In my previous question is on how to search only the date range between two dtpicker in 1 table only

Comment: Can you tell us about the other table? Your current query only uses one table (`tbl_Checklist`). You can still use UNION as was suggested for a previous question.

Comment: the other table is tbl_Dross it has 15 columns while tbl_checklist has  9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNION to merge the two tables and apply the same WHERE clause:

```
SELECT CheckItem AS 'Check Item', ItemNo AS 'Item No', Criteria, CheckDate FROM tbl_checklist WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN #" & DTPicker2 & "# AND #" & DTPicker3 & "#"
UNION
SELECT CheckItem AS 'Check Item', ItemNo AS 'Item No', Criteria, CheckDate FROM tbl_Dross WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN #" & DTPicker2 & "# AND #" & DTPicker3 & "#"
```

Since you have uneven number of columns, you will have to either merge some of the fields together or only return common columns. For example, if your `a1`, `a2` and `a3` fields contain either OK or NOT OK, then the following could be used to combine them into one field:

```
IIF(a1 = 'OK' AND a2 = 'OK' AND a3 = 'OK', 'OK', 'NOT OK') AS AMstart
```

or you could concatenate fields into one:

```
SELECT a1 + '-' + a2 + '-' + a3 AS AMstart
```

Here's an example that uses both:

```
SELECT CheckItem AS 'Check Item', ItemNo AS 'Item No', Criteria, CheckDate, AMstart, AMafter, PMstart, PMafter, Mcname FROM tbl_checklist WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN #" & DTPicker2 & "# AND #" & DTPicker3 & "#"
UNION
SELECT CheckItem AS 'Check Item', ItemNo AS 'Item No', Criteria, CheckDate, a1 + '-' + a2 + '-' + a3 AS AMstart, IIF(a4 = 'OK' AND a5 = 'OK' AND a6 = 'OK', 'OK', 'NOT OK') AS AMafter, a7 + '-' + a8 + '-' + a9 AS PMstart, IIF(a10 = 'OK' AND a11 = 'OK' AND a12 = 'OK', 'OK', 'NOT OK') AS PMafter, Mcname FROM tbl_Dross WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN #" & DTPicker2 & "# AND #" & DTPicker3 & "#"
```

Comment: Is it possible to join 2 table with different columns sir ?

Comment: Yes but as you join them you will have to make the number of columns the same. If you provide us with the structure of both tables you want to merge we can better assist you.

Comment: tbl1 column ; checkitem,itemno,criteria,am1,am2,pm1,pm2,mc1,checkdate
tbl2 column; checkitem,itemno,criteria,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,Mc1,Checkdate

Comment: So you have 4 columns in common and the rest are different. You can possibly merge `a1`, `a2`, `a3` into `am1`; `a4`, `a5`, `a6` into `am2`, etc. That way you will have matching amount of columns and things should work.

Comment: @ ÉtienneLaneville  how to code because I got some error that match table1 column to table2 column

Comment: Update your question with your current code and the error you are getting so people can help. Right now we have very little information to help you with.